# Change XML Animation android to dynamic code

Tags: android, android-animation

I have this Animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

But i have to make it dynamic in my code:

```
AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(false);
animSet.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(AddPhoto.this,
     android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
ScaleAnimation zoom = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
   zoom.setDuration(2000);
  animSet.addAnimation(zoom);
```

But it's not the same, what did i do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set the PivotX and PivotY. Use the following ScaleAnimator constructor

```
public ScaleAnimation (float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, 
                       float pivotX, float pivotY)


 Parameters

 fromX  Horizontal scaling factor to apply at the start of the animation
 toX    Horizontal scaling factor to apply at the end of the animation
 fromY  Vertical scaling factor to apply at the start of the animation
 toY    Vertical scaling factor to apply at the end of the animation
 pivotX The X coordinate of the point about which the object is being scaled, 
            specified as an absolute number where 0 is the left edge. (This point
            remains fixed while the object changes size.)
 pivotY The Y coordinate of the point about which the object is being scaled, 
            specified as an absolute number where 0 is the top edge. (This point
            remains fixed while the object changes size.)
```